# How to make this html components correclty responsive & avoid overlapping using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

In this code, i want to  make this html form correctly responsive & avoid overlapping  (shown in the image).If you run the code you will see  the components[Designation & Designation Code ] are overlapping over each other and displaying in wrong position.However these components are responsive as you minimize the browser screen, these components become vertically align from inline align.But the components[Faculty/Institute & Faculty/Institute Code ] are NOT overlapping over each other and displaying in Correct position.However these components are NOT responsive as you minimize the browser screen, these components will NOT vertically align from inline align.So, in this situation, How can i make all of these components **correctly responsive** [so that they can  components become vertically align for small screen] and at the same time in **correct position** [like other components shown here] .I just use this single file. what modifications are needed to resolve this?Please suggest.please let me know for further information.Thanks.
[image]

html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Employee Joining Information</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<!--  Comments   -->


<script type="text/javascript">

function updateText(type) { 
 var id = type+'Text';
 document.getElementById(id).value = document.getElementById(type).value;
}
</script>   


<style type="text/css">
    .bs-example{
        margin: 20px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>



<div class="container">
     <form class="form-horizontal container" style="border: 1px solid; padding: 10px">
        <h1 align="center">Employee Joining Information Form</h1>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label type="text" class="control-label col-xs-2">Employee ID</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eid">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label type="text" class="control-label col-xs-2">Name</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nm">
            </div>
        </div>




        <div class="form-group " id="DesignationForm">      
            <div class="form-inline">
                    <label type="text" class="control-label " >Designation</label>
                    <div class="form-group">        
                        <select class="form-control  col-xs-5" id="designation" onchange="updateText('designation')" >
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Select Designation</option>          
                            <option value="04">Chairman</option>                            
                        </select>               
                    </div>  

                    <label type="text" class="control-label " >Designation Code </label>    
                    <div class="form-group ">                               
                        <input type="text" value="" id="designationText" />
                    </div>      
            </div>
        </div>  


        <div class="form-group">
            <label type="text" class="control-label col-xs-2">Faculty/Institute</label> 
        <div class="col-xs-5">  
        <select class="form-control  col-xs-5"  id="facultyinstitute" onchange="updateText('facultyinstitute')">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Faculty / Institute</option>      
        <option value="10" >Faculty 1</option>
        <option value="20">Faculty 2</option>       
        </select>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-5">
        <label type="text" class="control-label " >Faculty/Institute Code </label>              
        <input type="text" value="" id="facultyinstituteText" />
        </div>
        </div>      
        </div>      
        </div>
        </div>
```

After looking useful comments i modify the code.But still it is **Not  correctly positioned  comparing to other input fields**[such as input box: Employee ID box, Name, Faculty/Institute box Faculty/Institute Code etc are correctly positioned  look at the 2nd image given below.]
[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYwd4.png)
here is the modified bootstrap html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Employee Joining Information</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<!--  Comments   -->


<script type="text/javascript">

function updateText(type) { 
 var id = type+'Text';
 document.getElementById(id).value = document.getElementById(type).value;
}
</script>   


<style type="text/css">
    .bs-example{
        margin: 20px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>



<div class="container">
     <form class="form-horizontal container" style="border: 1px solid; padding: 10px">
        <h1 align="center">Employee Joining Information Form</h1>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label type="text" class="control-label col-xs-2">Employee ID</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eid">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label type="text" class="control-label col-xs-2">Name</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nm">
            </div>
        </div>




        <div class="form-group " id="DesignationForm">      
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                <label type="text" class="control-label " >Designation</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">        
                    <select class="form-control  col-xs-5" id="designation" onchange="updateText('designation')" >
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Designation</option>          
                        <option value="04">Chairman</option>                            
                    </select>               
                </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                <label type="text" class="control-label " >Designation Code </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group ">                               
                    <input type="text" value="" id="designationText" />
                </div>  
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>  





        <div class="form-group">
            <label type="text" class="control-label col-xs-2">Faculty/Institute</label> 
        <div class="col-xs-5">  
        <select class="form-control  col-xs-5"  id="facultyinstitute" onchange="updateText('facultyinstitute')">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Faculty / Institute</option>      
        <option value="10" >Faculty 1</option>
        <option value="20">Faculty 2</option>       
        </select>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-5">
        <label type="text" class="control-label " >Faculty/Institute Code </label>              
        <input type="text" value="" id="facultyinstituteText" />
        </div>
        </div>


        </div>

        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:
http://plnkr.co/edit/AyjY07y26eQ2kDK23vis?p=preview

```
<div class="form-group " id="DesignationForm">      
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                <label type="text" class="control-label " >Designation</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">        
                    <select class="form-control  col-xs-5" id="designation" onchange="updateText('designation')" >
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Designation</option>          
                        <option value="04">Chairman</option>                            
                    </select>               
                </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                <label type="text" class="control-label " >Designation Code </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group ">                               
                    <input type="text" value="" id="designationText" />
                </div>  
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Basically, define col-xs-12 for small screen (full row span) and something less than that for higher resolutions. I used col-md-2 and col-md-4 so all 4 components combined fit the full container.

Comment: Thanks @cen.But still i got display positioning issue.please check  my post again ,i just updated it.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't make it perfect, just as an example. You can try adding extra padding to the form wrapper and use pull-right (float right) on labels to make them right aligned. I'd also suggest to put the other inputs into the same row-col structure so they will all be in the same type of container and also behave the same.